# login success trigger in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I have a trigger for login success in laravel.
Whenever a login is successful, a global variable should be set.
Is there a way I can use app:after ?

```
 App::after( function( $request ) { ... } )
```

---

I have this piece of code in my `UserController`:

```
function postLogin(){
    if ( login OK ){
        View::share('var', 'value');
    }
}
```

but the in view , output is :
`undefined variable : var`

I think if I set this global variable in filters.php, it set before rendering layout and will work. But I do not know how can use app:filter

Someone told me, whenever a login is successful, `app::after` will run, but it's not true
I echo out some value, whenever page is loading. it echo out the text after all requests. and this is more logical indeed.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `auth.login` event for this.

Here's a simple code for listening for a successful login:

```
Event::listen('user.login', function($user)
{
    // Things to do after a successful login
});
```

But this may not fit your needs. I think you want to control the login status on every page. Here's the code to check if the user is logged in:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    View::share('var', 'value');
}
```

Comment: the first part of your code is exactly what I want. a global var should be set once and after login successful. thank you.

Comment: `user.login` says any request from user/login view ?